# uninstalled yeoman, now npm not found

Tags: node.js, npm, yeoman

I decided to try out yeoman so I ran the following command:

`-bash: sudo npm install -g yo`

I received warnings that npm was outdated, so I figured, i'd uninstall yeoman, run any global and local npm updates and then reinstall yeoman.

`-bash: sudo npm uninstall -g yo`

The trouble is now it seems npm is no longer available. I receive the following

`-bash: npm: command not found`

Checking my .bash_profile file the only path declared is for git. Could yeoman have removed node/npm paths from the .bash_profile file?

How should I go about fixing this issue?
Thanks

Comment: How did you initally installed npm?

Comment: node.js install from node website.

Comment: npm by itself won't do anything that has an impact on the system, including changing the path, not even when uninstalling yeoman or any other package, so you can rule that out.